# How to transform grouped dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
bin=[0,5,10]

code sex age
a     1   1
a     1   6
b     1   8
b     2   2
c     2   3
c     1   4
```

I summarized this df like

```
 df.groupby([df.code,df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)]).size().unstack().stack().fillna(0)
```

I get result like below

```
code sex    age
a    1  (0,5] 1
a    1 (5,10] 1
a    2  (0,5] 0
a    2 (5,10] 0
b    1  (0,5] 0
b    1 (5,10] 1
b    2  (0,5] 1
b    2 (5,10] 0
c    1  (0,5] 1
c    1 (5,10] 0
c    2  (0,5] 1
c    2 (5,10] 0
```

I would like to transform this df to like

```
        1     2
        a b c  a b c
 (0,5]  1 0 1  0 1 1
(5,10]  1 0 0  0 0 0
```

I tried stack() or unstack() but I totally confused to transform to above dataframe.
How can I transform them?
some one tell me how to transform df like this process.

Comment: i can't reproduce your intermediate result based on your code.

Comment: Have you tried pivot_table instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  code  sex  age
0    a    1    1
1    a    1    6
2    b    1    8
3    b    2    2
4    c    2    3
5    c    1    4

In [12]: df.pivot_table(index=pd.cut(df.age, bins),
                        columns=["sex", "code"],
                        aggfunc="count",
                        fill_value=0)
Out[12]:
        age
sex       1        2
code      a  b  c  a  b  c
age
(0, 5]    1  0  1  0  1  1
(5, 10]   1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Note: any time you see stack/unstack think pivot_table!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.reset_index().set_index(['sex','code','age']).unstack(-1).T
Out[760]: 
sex           1        2      
code          a  b  c  a  b  c
      age                     
value (0,5]   1  0  1  0  1  1
      (5,10]  1  1  0  0  0  0
```

Data input :

```
Out[762]: 
                 value
code sex age          
a    1   (0,5]       1
         (5,10]      1
     2   (0,5]       0
         (5,10]      0
b    1   (0,5]       0
         (5,10]      1
     2   (0,5]       1
         (5,10]      0
c    1   (0,5]       1
         (5,10]      0
     2   (0,5]       1
         (5,10]      0
```

Or `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(index=pd.cut(df.age, bin),
                        columns=[df.sex, df.code])
Out[768]: 
sex      1        2   
code     a  b  c  b  c
age                   
(0, 5]   1  0  1  1  1
(5, 10]  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: It's all about the pivot_table (if you see stack/unstack think pivot_table)! This doesn't handle the case that the value is > 1 ... not sure if that's possible in OPs data. Edit: I take it back, that's handled in the `.size()` of the OPs code!

Comment: @AndyHayden adding `crosstab` method .

Comment: :D haha, great!

Answer (score 1):

On the dataframe you have given, do

```
df.set_index(['code','sex']).unstack(['code','sex'])
```

In the future, please give your data in a form that allows others to run themselves, e.g. the output from `df.to_records()` or `df.to_json()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, only is necessary specify parameter `level` in `unstack` and last sort columns:

```
df = df.groupby([df.code,df.sex,pd.cut(df.age,bin)])
       .size()
       .unstack(level=[1,0])
       .sort_index(axis=1)
       .fillna(0)
print (df)
sex        1              2     
code       a    b    c    b    c
age                             
(0, 5]   1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
(5, 10]  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```